registerForActivityResult isn't showing window animations
I have a fragment that's opening a map activity using code that looks like this:
private val openMapResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    presenter.onMapActivityResult(result.resultCode, result.data)
}

and I launch the activity with
openMapResultLauncher.launch(intent)
My activity is basic and has an assigned theme via the AndroidManifest that looks like this:
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MapActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MapTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"/>

And here's my Theme:
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MapTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MapTheme.WindowAnimationStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MapTheme.WindowAnimationStyle">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_enter</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/activity_exit</item>
    </style>
</resources>

I cannot get any control over the animations that run when the Activity is launched.  I've tried everything I can think of and it always just uses the zoom from center default animation, while I'm trying to get it to slide in from the right.
I've tried
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(requireActivity(), R.anim.activity_enter, R.anim.activity_exit)
        openMapResultLauncher.launch(intent, options)

and I've tried
requireActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_enter, R.anim.activity_exit)

What am I doing wrong?

Based on: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/transitions/start-activity#custom-trans
It looks like you can just define them in the theme directly, e.g.
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MapTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_enter</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/activity_exit</item>
    </style>
</resources>

There are also other various theme properties:
android:activityOpenEnterAnimation
android:activityOpenExitAnimation
android:activityCloseEnterAnimation
android:activityCloseExitAnimation

